# BigQuery: Table name missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is the issue with a BigQuery query.
I know this query is missing a dataset name, so the error **"Table name "my_table" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request."**

`select * from my_table;`

Changing 'my_tabale' to 'my_dataset.my_table' will fix the issue.
But can somebody help me with setting a default dataset.
The error message clearly giving an indication that BigQuery has such an option.

Comment: sadly, it seems that as for today there is no way to do this via the browser console

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which API you are using, you can specify the `defaultDataset` parameter when running your BigQuery job. More information for the `jobs.query` api can be found here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query.

For example, using the NodeJS API for `createQueryJob` https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#createQueryJob, you can do something similar to this:

```
const options = {
  keyFilename: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
  projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_PROJECT_ID,
  defaultDataset: {
    datasetId: process.env.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID,
    projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_PROJECT_ID
  },
  query: `select * from my_table;`
}

const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
let [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
```

Comment: Thanks @bitnahian for your answer.
I am just using the BigQuery console to run this query. It is not with any other specific BQ api. I have multiple datasets, looking for an option to set the current one as the default dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: `SET @@dataset_id = 'whatever';`

But, this is a scripting command, so you will have to enclose your SQL query in a BEGIN ... END block.  Note the semicolon.  Scripting gives you some added flexibility.  On the other hand, it prevents the console from doing that fun thing where it estimates the processing cost.